# Send PDF file from PHP to android app

Tags: php, android, pdf

I am generating PDF file dynamically in PHP and I have to output that PDF file in my android app I am developing. I have to output and display that PDF file. The problem is that I don't know how to send that PDF file from the PHP to the android app and how to make the android app open the PDF?

Comment: download it via http using a browser control. it'll pop up in the system default pdf viewer, most likely.

Comment: Marc B : I have no idea about it..could you post a tutorial or website to help me please. Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to output a PDF in a browser; inline and attachment.

In PHP set your content disposition, filename, and content type:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
```

or

```
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=myfile.pdf");
```

then echo the contents of the pdf as a string.

In your app, if you have a broswer window pointed to the url, the file should open up in whatever you've set your default PDF viewer to be.  Or if you're using the inline disposition, it may open up right in the application.

Comment: Peter..for the server side its done but I can't open the pdf in the android app.

Comment: I know squat about android programming save that the android browser will handle PHP files natively.  What I'm saying is, open up a browser controller in the app, point it to the file, and let the webkit engine render the PDF.